# Creating custom install for windows service in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation

I'm having a windows service and a custom console install that should install it (among other things it does - so I can't use .msi installation from Setup Project).

The code uses installutil.exe to do the installation but 3.5 framework doesn't have this exe. How to install such service? 
It needs to run on both 32bit and 64bit and on machines that don't have VS, just framework 3.5

(I looked around the site and found several answers but none of them is applicable here)

**Update**:
If I use version from 2.xx I get an exception:

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly xxx or
>   one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer
>   than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code uses installutil.exe to do the installation but 3.5 framework doesn't have this exe.

I have an out of the box installation of .net3.5 and it ships with installutil.exe

Look in

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

Remember that .NET3.5 still runs on the .net2 *runtime*

Answer (score 2):

The 3.5 framework *does* have that application.

Look in the directory

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\

or something similar.  That is where **installutil.exe** lives for .NET 3.5 (it uses the same platform at .NET 2, which is why the folder is called as such).

So you should be able to call **installutil.exe** using that full path.

Comment: I agree, but if I do that I get exception System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly xxx or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.. Will update my initial question with this info.

Comment: @FedorHajdu Have you tried using the `InstallUtil.exe` that lives in the **Framework64** folder?  If you are truly on .NET 3.5 with your assembly, then this installutil should succeed.

Comment: I didn't before you suggested it but I did now and it still throws the same exception.